# What is the meaning of "p_y_given_x_sentence = s[:, 0, :]" in rnnslu.py

Tags: theano

What does `p_y_given_x_sentence = s[:, 0, :]` in file `rnnslu.py` mean?
I assume that s is two dimensional.  Where does `s[:, 0, :]` come from?

Comment: What type is `s`?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thank you for your comment, this question is about a code line in [rnnslu.py](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/rnnslu.py). You can see that s is defined as follows:
```
        [h, s], _ = theano.scan(fn=recurrence,
                                sequences=x,
                                outputs_info=[self.h0, None],
                                n_steps=x.shape[0])

        p_y_given_x_sentence = s[:, 0, :] 
```